# Eigen c++ map two matrices to a new one by even and odd rows without copying

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I'm using Eigen, and I have two matrices A(a,b) and B(c,d) which I'd like to compose into a new one C(a+c, b=d) while having odd rows from A and even rows from B.

Now a and c are rows, b and d are columns, and I'd like to use Map so values are not copied. Of course loops are not welcomed, unless they can avoid copying. ;-)

Thank you

EDIT: Use case is: A and B are vertices and normals separated matrix of a mesh,

```
VectorXd A(a,b); -- vertices
VectorXd B(c,d); -- normals
```

while C is a vertices and normal single object into a point cloud.

```
struct Point{
    VectorXd A; -- vertices
    VectorXd B; -- normals
}
```

Copying here means doubling the memory usage

EDIT: Forgot to say b=d is even

Comment: Seems like an x-y problem. What are you trying to achieve with this. Much better to incur a one-time copy than a multiple-time indirection in using the matrix.

Comment: I'm curious what the use case for this is. Is it that you want `C` to automatically update when `A` or `B` change? If this is performance reasons, you are probably looking in the wrong direction.

Comment: With existing functionality you could probably first create the final `C` matrix and have `A` and `B` as Maps inside that. Or create a custom `NullaryExpr` (https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicCustomizing_NullaryExpr.html -- this link just shows a vague direction, not a solution to your problem)